# Example of oscillating sequence and compactness in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined in the following way:
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x \in [\frac{i}{n} + \frac{i}{n^2}, \frac{i+1/2}{n} - \frac{i}{n^2}] \\
0 & \text{ if } x \in [\frac{i+1/2}{n}, \frac{i+1}{n} - \frac{i}{n^2}] \\
1 & \text{ if } x = \frac{i+1/2}{n} - \frac{i}{n^2} \\
1 &  \text{ if } x =\frac{i+1/2}{n} +\frac{i}{n^2}
\end{cases}
 \quad \text{ for } i = 0,1, 2,3,..., n-1
$$
**and interpolating with a straight line between 0 and 1 in the missing intervals** (this looks like triangular spikes that eventually that get more and more dense).

- Is this sequence relatively compact in $L^p([0,1])$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In view of reflexivity any norm bounded sequence in $L^{p}$ has a weakly convergent subsequence  for $1 <p<\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, this is clear. But I don't know if it also converges strongly.

Comment: @supinf Continuing my previous comment: it seems not because it does not have bounded total variation (but this is is just a sufficient condition, not necessary).